# Simulating Dependent Random Variables in R

Tags: r, dependencies

Given means and standard deviations from three (or potentially more) random variables X, Y and Z and their variance-covariance matrix, how can I generate/simulate a set of random numbers in R. Any existing package to do this? Thank you!

Comment: How are your variables distributed?? Multinomial?Multivariatenormal?? etc

Comment: The `mvtnorm` package is a good one to draw random values from multivariate normal (or t-)distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw from a multivariate normal distribution.

```
library(mvtnorm)

# Some mean vector and a covariance matrix
mu <- colMeans(iris[1:50, -5])
cov <- cov(iris[1:50, -5])

# genrate n = 100 samples
sim_data <- rmvnorm(n = 100, mean = mu, sigma = cov)

# visualize in a pairs plot 
pairs(sim_data)
```